# Python get all elements from a listbox

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a Flask and Python web application where  I implement CRUD methods for two objects: **Team** and **Employee**; in a many to many relationship. An Employee could be a member of multiple Teams, and a Team could have multiple Employees.

Now, when I create a Team, I have two listboxes: one with all the employee and one with employees that will be part of the team. With two buttons, I can move employees from one listbox to another and viceversa.

At the end, I can press a button Add to create the team in a Sqlite3 database where I have three tables: employee, team, teams_employees.

The github.com project is [this](https://github.com/sasadangelo/benjamin).

The HTML form is the [following code on github.com](https://github.com/sasadangelo/benjamin/blob/42a3ac8bcce4131faf098afcae7846b27499e17b/app/templates/create-team.html#L13-L38).

Then I have a controller Python method [like this](https://github.com/sasadangelo/benjamin/blob/42a3ac8bcce4131faf098afcae7846b27499e17b/app/controllers/teams_controller.py#L19-L32). The problem is that this call:

```
'team_members': request.form.getlist('team_members[]')
```

returns only the selected employee in the team members listbox. What I need is to change this line of code to haave all the employee in the team_members listbox indipendently whether they are selected or not.

Can anyone suggest me how to change the code to have this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior on form submit is that the **value(s)** of each HTML widget is submitted. The value of a select element are the **selected** options.

To meet your goal,

1. Create a hidden text input element whose value is a comma separated string of all the values of your select element. You retrieve this value in flask (it will come as a string) and then you split on `","` to get your array of values.
2. An alternative of the above is that you when your form is submitted, you intercept the submit via Javascript and then programmatically do bullet 1.

**Updated** (added sample code)

**Sample List of employees**

```
employees = [{"id":100, "name":"John James"}, 
    {"id":200, "name":"Mary Kay"}, 
    {"id":300, "name":"Kent Clark"}]
```

**HTML FORM**

```
<form method="POST" action="/post-form/">
...
<!-- Get ONLY the names of all employees -->
{% set all_employees =  employees | selectattr("name") | map(attribute="name") | list %}

<input value="{{all_employees}}"  style="display:none;" name="all_employees"/>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**FLASK CODE**

```
@app.route("/post_form/", methods=["POST"])
def process_form():
    all_employees = request.values.get("all_employees")
    
    # You'll get a list of all employees on the screen
    return(all_employees)
```

Comment: I tried but still get only the selected items. You said: "Create a hidden text input element whose value is a comma separated string of all the values of your select element. ". How can I implement this?

Comment: Include the code you used (for this input element) in your Post

Comment: I've added code for you. I tested it and confirmed it works